# Remove permission from public

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

please see snap shoot below.I was wondering why I can't remove the permission with following code. But I can remove the permission by using the GUI.

REVOKE ALL ON OBJECT::[dbo].[Table1] FROM [PUBLIC];

[image]

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: "Command(s) completed successfully." But the permission still there, the query seem no affected

Comment: I tried its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It tested this on SQL Server 2005, and the query works fine. However, do not expect the table Properties dialog to update automatically, not even after moving forward and back to another page, like Storage. You must close and reopen the dialog to see the modifications.

I checked this by running the following script in steps:

Source: [How to list permissions for Public Role for a database in SQL Server](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1623469-how-list-permissions-public-role-database-sql-server.html).

```
grant select, insert, update on dbo.Table1 to public
GO

SELECT a.[name] + ' ' + v.[name] + ' ON ' + QuoteName(oo.[name]) 
+ '.' + QuoteName(o.[name]) + ' TO ' + QuoteName(u.[name])
   FROM dbo.sysprotects AS p
   JOIN master.dbo.spt_values AS a
      ON (a.number = p.protecttype
      AND 'T' = a.type)
   JOIN master.dbo.spt_values AS v
      ON (v.number = p.action
      AND 'T' = v.type)
   JOIN dbo.sysobjects AS o
      ON (o.id = p.id)
   JOIN dbo.sysusers AS oo
      ON (oo.uid = o.uid)
   JOIN dbo.sysusers AS u
      ON (u.uid = p.uid)
   WHERE  'public' = u.name
GO

revoke all on object::dbo.Table1 to public
GO

-- Run query again
```

Please note that a warning is issued when using **revoke all**: *The ALL permission is deprecated and maintained only for compatibility. It DOES NOT imply ALL permissions defined on the entity.*